# SQL View to return Listing of Effective Products

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Please assist with creating an SQL view.

On DB2 For i V7R2

**Situation:**

Departments at my company are allowed to sell a listing of products,
up until they are replace with a new product. On the day that the new product becomes effective the Department is allowed to sell both Products.
At the COB, the old product is no longer allowed to be sold, and needs to be returned.

**Required:**

SQL query to return the listing of "allowed" products for a specific date.

The query needs to return:

"Green-Ladder" and "Red-Ladder" `WHERE EFFDAT = CURRENT_DATE

**Example Data Set:**

```
drop table QTEMP/Product_EffectiveDate_TestTable;

create table  QTEMP/Product_EffectiveDate_TestTable (
    Dept    varchar(50) not null,
    EffDat  date        not null,
    PrdCde  varchar(50) not null);

insert into  QTEMP/Product_EffectiveDate_TestTable
    ( Dept, EffDat, PrdCde)
 values
    ('Department A', CURRENT_DATE + 10 DAY  , 'Blue-Ladder'),
    ('Department A', CURRENT_DATE           , 'Green-Ladder'),
    ('Department A', CURRENT_DATE - 10 DAY  , 'Red-Ladder'),
    ('Department A', CURRENT_DATE - 20 DAY  , 'Yellow-Ladder') ;
```

Comment: Your test data does not include superseded products. And, for `current_date` I would expect to see `Product1`, `Product2`, and `Product3`, based on your text description. Why are you omitting `Product1` from your list of valid responses?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Product1 is valid up until and including (CURRENT_DATE - 10 DAYS)

Comment: How do I know that? What links the two together? Or can a given department only sell a single product?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Product1 is superseded by Product2 when Product2's becomes effective. On that day BOTH Product1 and Product2 can be sold by the same department.

Comment: Ok, let me give you an example. The Pools and Spas department sells swimming pools (Product1), diving boards (Product2), and ladders (Product3). They introduce a new and improved diving board (Product4) to supersede the old diving board (Product2). If I only have the fields you provided, how do I know `Product4` supersedes `Product2`, and not `Product1` or `Product3`?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy A given Department can sell only a single Product. I have ammended the Example to reflect this.

Comment: Given this information, see my more complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer for a single product per department is:

```
select * 
  from qtemp.Product_EffectiveDate_TestTable a
  where effdat = (select max(effdat) 
                  from qtemp.Product_EffectiveDate_TestTable
                  where effdat < current_date
                    and dept = a.dept)
     or effdat = current_date
```

You can convert this to a view if you are only interested in products for the current date. However if you want to be able to query it for any given date, you will have to create a table function.

The view would look something like this:

```
create view Products_By_Department as
select * 
  from qtemp.Product_EffectiveDate_TestTable a
  where effdat = (select max(effdat) 
                  from qtemp.Product_EffectiveDate_TestTable
                  where effdat < current_date
                    and dept = a.dept)
     or effdat = current_date;
```

The UTF could look like this:

```
create or replace function xxxxxx.UTF_ProductsByDepartment
  (
    p_date Date
  )
  returns table
  (
    Dept    Varchar(50),
    EffDat  Date,
    PrdCde  Varchar(50),
  )
  language sql
  reads sql data
  no external action
  not deterministic
  disallow parallel
  return
    select dept, effdat, prdcde 
      from qtemp.Product_EffectiveDate_TestTable a
      where effdat = (select max(effdat) 
                      from qtemp.Product_EffectiveDate_TestTable
                      where effdat < p_date
                        and dept = a.dept)
         or effdat = p_date;
```

You would use the UTF like this:

```
select * from table(xxxxxx.utf_ProductsByDepartment(date('2017-06-13'))) a
```

Note that you cannot put a function in QTEMP, so you will have to replace `xxxxxx` with an appropriate library, or you can leave it unqualified, and set the default schema some other way.

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

**I would solve this by changing your data design if possible.**  It would be preferable to have a start and end date on each row.  Reasons:

- **It makes for a much simpler query.**
- **It's a clearer, easier to understand design.**
- **It is more flexible, allowing future changes to your business requirements.** "Hey, actually we need to still sell this old version of the product" is the kind of pernicious requirement that has a way of popping up later, and ideally you would be able to handle this without rewriting application code.

In the event that you can't change the data design, I would use a subquery to create the end date:

```
with start_end_dates as (
    select Dept,
           EffDat as start_date,
           lead (EffDat) over (partition by Dept order by EffDat) as   end_date,
           ProdCd
       from table
)
select * from start_end_dates where
    current date between start_date and coalesce(end_date,'9999-12-31');
```

This assumes that the effective date refers to rows within a particular department.  Alter the partition clause as necessary if that's not true.

Comment: lead() is not supported on my version of DB2. Can't change the data design :(

Comment: @ChristoffErasmus in that case number the rows order by date, and self join to the row number 1 higher to get the next effective date.